# Add children of children user control to parent

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implement toolbox like control in WPF using User controls. I'm able to get the all Titles of UCITems and shown as tabs in UCTab and binded to StackPanel in UCTab using ContentProperty. But I need UCItem childrens also and bind to another stack panel in UCTab.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:UCTab>
        <local:UCItem Title="ToolBox 1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="2"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="3"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </local:UCItem>
        <local:UCItem Title="ToolBox 2"></local:UCItem>
        <local:UCItem Title="ToolBox 3"></local:UCItem>

    </local:UCTab>`
```

UCTab UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserTab.UCTab "
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserTab"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>        
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Name="bd" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="50" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="host" >

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="bdCanvas" Grid.Column="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="SkyBlue" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="spPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Width="180" >
                <Grid Background="Navy">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Text="Heading" Margin="3" ></TextBlock>
                    <Button x:Name="btnPin" Content="P" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="X" Margin="3" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
                </Grid>

                <StackPanel x:Name="panelUCItem"  > 

                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

UCITem UserCotrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserTab.UCITem "
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserTab"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UCITem }">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UCITem }">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="Gray"
                        Margin="5">
                        <Button x:Name="tbItem" Padding="5" Width="100" Height="28" Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding Title,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <Button.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
                            </Button.LayoutTransform>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

On click of UCItem button, display UCItem content Stackpanel 'panelUCItem' in UCTab.

Help me how I can proceed with this structure. Thanks

Comment: Please try to reword, provide an example, or something. Its very hard to tell where you are stuck

Comment: Update with code.